# Efficient storage of UNICODED text for processing with Blaze/Pandas

Tags: postgresql, pandas, unicode, blaze, nosql

I have about 5 million (& growing) rows of twitter feed and I want to store them efficiently for faster read / write access using Pandas (Preferably [Blaze](http://blaze.pydata.org)). From that huge metadata of a single tweet, I am just storing `[username, tweet time, tweet & tweet ID]`. So it's not much. Also, all the tweets are `unicode` encoded. Now what's the best way to store this data? I am currently storing them in a bunch of CSVs but I don't find it as a viable solution as the data grows and hence plan to move to a DB. I first thought of HDF5 but it still has [issues](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11126) storing unicoded columns (even in Python 3).

Since Blaze has excellent support for databases (& I think is great for analytics too), may I know what can be a good architectural solution (at production level, if possible) to my problem? As my data is also structured, I don't feel the need for a NoSQL solution but am open to suggestions.

Currently, those 5 MM rows occupy only about 1 GB of space and I don't think it will ever cross a few tens of GB. So, is using `Postgres`, the best idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `PostgresSQL` is a perfectly fine choice for your 10s of GB application. I've had an easy time using `sqlalchemy` with the `psycopg2` driver, and the `psql` command line tool is fine.

[There is an incredible command-line interface to PostgresSQL called `pgcli` that offers tab-completion for table and column names.](http://pgcli.com/) I highly recommend it, and just this tool might be enough to push you to use PostgresSQL.